# Express routes with parameter

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have two express APIs one to update one record and the second is to restore multi records 
I use Express 4.17.1

Front end APIs

```
update API
fetch(`/api/airlines/${this.state.id}`, {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify({data: this.StaticRange.data}),
})

Restore API
fetch('/api/airlines/restore', {
  method: 'put',
  signal: this.signal,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ ids: this.state.checkedRecords }),
})
```

Controler API

```
update API
 app.put('/api/airlines/:id', airlines.updateOne);

 Restore API
 app.put('/api/airlines/restore', airlines.restoreMulti);
```

when I call Update API everything is OK, but when I call Reactor API It calls
airlines .restoreMulti and airlines.updateOne and in airlines.updateOne when I console params I got { id: 'restore' }.
Also when I change the restore URL to  `'/api/airlines/restore/multi'`  It's work and only calls airlines.restoreMulti.
Is there something wrong in `'/api/airlines/restore'`

Comment: `/api/airlines/restore` also matches the pattern `/api/airlines/:id` with an id of restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the explicit URL (i.e. the Restore API) before the URL with the route parameter.

Reason being, `:id` will match any string after `/api/airlines`, therefore `/api/airlines/restore` is a valid match. Declaring explicit routes first allows you to handle those URLs before they get caught by the route parameter.